# Show that $f_n(x)=\sqrt n\, x^n$ diverges in $\big( {\cal C}[0,1], d_2\big)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

let $f_n\in{\cal C}[0,1]$ be given by
$f_n(x)=\sqrt n\, x^n$.

We choose a $g \in \mathcal C[0, 1]$, we know that $\|g\|_2 \geq 0$ and $\|g\|_2 \in \mathbb R$. We denote $\|g\|_2 = a \geq 0$.

I tried to calculate $d_2(f_n, g)$:
\begin{align*}
        d_2(f_n, g) & = \|g - f_n\|_2 \\
        % & = \left( \int_{0}^1 \left| g - f_n \right|^2 \right)^{1/2} \\
        & \geq \Big| \|g\|_2 - \|f_n\|_2 \Big| \qquad \text{ By Reverse Triangle Inequality}\\ 
        & = \left| \left( \int_{0}^1 |g|^2 \right)^{1/2} - \left( \int_{0}^1 |f_n|^2 \right)^{1/2} \right| \\
        & = \left| a - \sqrt{\frac{n}{2n + 1}} \right| 
    \end{align*}

However, when $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, that the above expression converges to 0 when $n \to \infty$. I can't seem to find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $d_2(f_n, g) \geq \epsilon$ for all $g \in \mathcal C[0, 1]$.

How can I prove that $f_n(x)=\sqrt n\, x^n$ diverges in $\big( {\cal C}[0,1], d_2\big)$ if using the Reverse Triangle Inequality is not the correct way to prove it?

Comment: notice the norm / integral of $f_n$ might converge, but that does not mean that $f_n$ converges to a function in $C[0,1]$ in $d_2$. Notice that a limit is also a point wise limit almost everywhere. So the only candidate for limit is the zero function. But the distance to zero is...? :)

Answer (score 2):

The point-wise limit is $0$ for $x <1$. If the sequence converges in $d_2$ the limit has to be $0$. But $\int|f_n(x)|^{2} dx =\frac n {2n+1} \to  \frac  1 2$. Hence the sequence does not converge.

$e^{t} \geq t$ for all $t \geq 0$. Put $t=n\ln (\frac 1 x)$ to get $\frac  1 {x^{n}} \geq n\ln (\frac 1 x)$ or $0 \leq \sqrt n x^{n} \leq \frac  1{ \sqrt n \ln (\frac 1 x)}$.  Hence the point-wise limit is $0$.

Alternative proof of almost everywhere convergence: If $y >1$ the $y^{n} =(1+(y-1)^{n}) >n(y-1)$ by Binomial expansion of $(1+(y-1))^{n}$. Hence $\frac {\sqrt n} {y^{n}} <\frac {\sqrt n} {n(y-1)} \to 0$. Put $y=\frac 1  x$ to see that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x \in [0,1)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the point-wise limit is 0" and "the sequence converges in $d_2$ the limit has to be 0"? I know that $d_2(f_n, 0) = \sqrt{\frac{n}{2n+1}}$. The limit for $d_2(f_n, 0)$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thus, $f_n$ does not converge to the zero function.

Comment: @Benjamin Answer edited.